# Deserialized object has null in all fields

Tags: java, serialization, null

I have written my `Container<T>` class which backups its `T` items in several collections -- primary one is `List<T>`, others are various maps with data derived from items, mostly for optimized search.

Class looks like this:

```
class Container<T> implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private final List<T> items = Lists.newArrayList();
    private final Map<...> map1 = Maps.newHashMap();
    private final Map<...> map2 = Maps.newHashMap();
}
```

Standard serialization works like a charm, but maps do not need to be serialized. I tried to set maps as `transient` and use `readObject()` in this way:

```
class Container<T> implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private final List<T> items = Lists.newArrayList();
    private transient Map<...> map1;
    private transient Map<...> map2;

    public Container() {
        initContainer();
    }

    private void readObject(ObjectInputStream in) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        in.defaultReadObject();
        initContainer();
    }

    private void initContainer() {
        map1 = Maps.newHashMap();
        map2 = Maps.newHashMap();
        // prepare data in maps
        for (T item: items) {
            map1.put(...);
            map2.put(...);
        }
    }
}
```

Simple test with `ObjectOutputStream.writeObject()` and `ObjectInputStream.readObject()` again works. But when I integrate `Container` to real application where is this class serialized and deserialized as a part of other complex classes (Wicket Page in fact), strange things happens.

I did some debugging and here are my findings:

- serialization of `Container` with (n) items has done OK
- deserialization of `Container` has done OK
- deserialization of each `T` item is called only (n-1) times (by counting calls to its `readObject()` method)
- in `containerInit()` had `List<T>` correct (n) number of items, but one of them (that one for which is not called deserialization) is in very strange state - **all fields have `null` value** - and my code here throws NPE

Questions:

- What state has that strange object after deserialization (it is existing but without `readObject()` call and with null in all fields)?
- Maybe deserialization of that strange object is not completed, but I have read that reading objects from `ObjectInputStream` is blocking, so all objects in my list must be in correct state. Or I something overlooked?
- Are there any technique/tool/practice for catching things like this?

Thank you.

Comment: A couple questions: Is the improperly deserialized object consistently the same one? If so, how does its state differ from the others? Also, whenever deserializing objects, it's a good idea to assume they're from a hostile source and check their state accordingly for things like nulls or anything else that compromise your app.

Comment: This object isn't same in every case, before serialization is referenced by couple of other objects in application -- it is completely healthy object before serialization calls its `writeObject()` method. 
  
I have one more important finding: when I don't traverse through `items` in `Container.readObject()` (or `initContainer()` in fact), everything works! It looks like I cannot touch right-now deserialized data in `readObject()`, it must be postponed after serialization is complete. Maybe it is dependent on existing references to object before serialization starts... very very strange...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I wrote in comment the problem was in touching items in serialized collection during `Container.readObject()`. Some of these objects had in this moment null fields. When I postponed their touching outside deserialization of `Container`, these objects had correct field values.

**My hypothesis**:

Lets have object **parent** with field collection of other objects **children**. Both parent and children are serializable, as well as collection. During customized parent deserialization in `readObject()` method aren't children fully accessible, they exists but its deserialization is not complete. You have to access children only after parent deserialization is processed.

This hypothesis works for me, but I still don't know why.